# Ajax form not submitting to controller action

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ajax form is not submitting to controller action. Here is the code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("searchCustomers", "Transaction", new { phoneNumber = Model.CustomerMobile }, new AjaxOptions
                {
                    UpdateTargetId = "custList",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                }))
                {
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Customer Mobile No:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CustomerMobile, new { @class = "form-control", id = "custMobile" })
                        </div>
                        @*<div class="form-group">
                            <label>Customer Name</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CustomerName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "custName" })
                        </div>*@
                        <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-default" value="Get Customer Details" >
                    </div>

                }
```

Here is the controller action

```
 public ActionResult searchCustomers(string phoneNumber)
    {
        if (phoneNumber==null)
        {
            return PartialView(new List<Models.Customer>());
        }

        var c = Database.Session.Query<Models.Customer>()
            .Where(x => x.MobileNumber.Like(phoneNumber) )
            .ToList();
        return PartialView(c);

    }
```

but the ajax form is not submitting. I've added the JavaScript files as bundles. I've another `@Html.Action("searchCustomers", new { phoneNumber = Model.CustomerMobile })` this one calls the controller action.

Comment: Does the custList element exists in your DOM? Just to make sure, your controller is called Transaction and you do have the proper route set, right?

Comment: Yes, there is a custList element and the controller name is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine in your code. There are two javascript files that are needed for **Ajax.Beginform** to work.

1. jquery-{Vaersion}.js
2. jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Check whether you have included those files to your view or not. Or if your view has any LayOut if those javascript files are included in your LayOut or not.

Comment: I have added them in the bundle

Comment: well..then is it included in layOut or the view ?

Comment: Check jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is there ?

Comment: do you have any script tag in this cshtml ?

Comment: the scripts are added in the _Layout.cshtml, No other script tags